# C/C++: Passing a string read to a loop inside a program in C

Tags: c++, c

I am working in a program that should read an user inputted string and use that string inside a loop for basic calculation.
My general problem is the use of the string inside a loop and, despite the fact that later it will have to do more, from now I only need to test Bolzano's Theorem (in particular to find possible intervals for roots) for the inputted expression.
I already started working into a function that reads the input char by char and with switch controls calculate the infix expression.
However, what I would like to know is if there is a way to do something like that:

```
{
    /*Already stored the doubles: a, b, precision.*/
    printf("Enter the expression you want to calculate");
    scanf("%s", expression);
    /*User input: (3*i)+(i*i)-3*/
    while( i <= b ){
       fa = (3*i)+(i*i)-3; /*How to insert the string here*/
       fb = (3*(i+precision))+((i+precision)*(i+precision))-3;
       if( fa*fb < 0 )
          printf("There is at least one root in the interval: [ %g, %g ].", a, a+precision);
       /*And goes on...*/
}
```

Supposing that the user does not input an invalid expression for the use in the loop (such as i^7) or that I already implemented controls to convert those expressions (something like read a string and change it to a postfix or prefix notation doing the necessary conversion), is there a way to use a stored string in a assignment into a loop?

Comment: In C or in C++? Maybe you want `atoi`?

Comment: `atoi` has some pretty terrible semantics - `strtol` is always a better choice.

Comment: You need an expression parser.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the technical term user93353, with this and Jens's answer I think I will be able to find some material for study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is: given a string with some mathematical expression, how do I evaluate that expression?

I don't know if you can make certain assumptions about the syntax of the expression; if so that would help you simplify your code.  If not, you basically would have to "tokenize" your string first, for above string that would be a sequence of tokens like this:

```
LBRACKET, NUM, BINOP, VAR, RBRACKET, BINOP, LBRACKET, VAR, BINOP, VAR, RBRACKET, BINOP, NUM
```

You'd also have to build yourself a little parser that makes sure your expression is formed based on certain syntactic rules; the parser would consume that sequence of tokens.  The output of the parser is then a data structure (usually a tree) that represents that expression.  Given that tree, you can evaluate the expression by computing sub-expressions bottom up.

```
fa =                       -
                          / \
                         +   3
                        / \
                       *   *
                      / \ / \
                     3  i i  i
```

It would be just a matter of adding new nodes into that tree to add your precision operands.

There's some stuff online on how to do this.  Just search for "how to build an expression evaluator" and for example [this](http://www.strchr.com/expression_evaluator) page comes up with some more details.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly that I needed. Apparently it will not be as easy as I thought but thanks for the answer and the link presented.

Comment: You're right, it's not a 5min hack but with some help you can automate these things.  There are tools that help you generate scanners (tokenizers) and parsers from descriptions, see `lex` or `flex` or `yacc` or `bison`; or even search for "online scanner generator" or "online parser generator".  Having said that, if you can ensure that your expression string has a certain form/syntax then you can just reach into it and pull tokes out of it.